# Laravel 4 error when changing password

Tags: php, encryption, change-password, laravel-4.2

My Controller

```
    public function update($id)
{
    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
        return \App::abort(404);
        // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }

    $temp = Input::all();

    $temp['password'] = Hash::make($temp['password']);

    //form Processing
    $result = $this->userForm->update($temp);
    //$result = $this->userForm->update(Input::all());

    if ($result['success']) {
        // Success!
        Session::flash('success', $result['message']);
        return Redirect::action('UserController@index', array($id));

    } else {
        Session::flash('error', $result['message']);
        return Redirect::action('UserController@edit', array($id))
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($this->userForm->errors());
    }
}
```

My View

```
    <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('firstName')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}" for="firstName">
    {{ Form::label('edit_firstName', 'First Name', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('firstName', $user->first_name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First
        Name', 'id' => 'edit_firstName'))}}
    </div>
    {{ ($errors->has('firstName') ? $errors->first('firstName') : '') }}
</div>


<div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('lastName')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}" for="lastName">
    {{ Form::label('edit_lastName', 'Last Name', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::text('lastName', $user->last_name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name',
        'id' => 'edit_lastName'))}}
    </div>
    {{ ($errors->has('lastName') ? $errors->first('lastName') : '') }}
</div>

@if (Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('admin'))
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('edit_memberships', 'Group Memberships', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'))}}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @foreach ($allGroups as $group)
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="groups[{{ $group->id }}]" value='1'
            {{ (in_array($group->name, $userGroups) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') }} > {{ $group->name }}
        </label>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('password')) ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
        {{ ($errors->has('password') ? $errors->first('password') : '') }}
</div>
@endif
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::hidden('id', $user->id) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Changes', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))}}
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close()}}</div>
```

I'm trying to update data profile like; first name, last name, member and password.
I cannot update this password, my encryption password like:
`$2y$10$mjkd5MRgUEn2JSK52xrrQ.bpDz5WZwAaHje6gd0TbmH7h4H3.7BBO`

Comment: A hash is not encryption. What is the question?

Comment: error update password! this password cant replace

Comment: @khakim What is the actual, specific error you're getting? "This password cant replace" is not a Laravel error, nor does it exist in your code.